# ReceiveMemoryWarning if open pdf (mupdf-library)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, mupdf

When we try to open a pdf file with a big image in it, we get an application crash. Before the crash the method **AppDelegate.ReceiveMemoryWarning** is being called.
The mupdf-library requires more space than the device can provide.
It is possible to limit the size library can use when processing a file?

(Using the variables **max_store** and **FZ_STORE_DEFAULT** does not help)

Comment: It might be tough to find an exact answer for this specific library.  Have you gone through their documentation for any size related processing?  Another approach might be to look into resizing and processing the image on your side before utilizing the library.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Set En! Could you please share the function in which you use the mupdf library and around where the crash occurs

Comment: @Kyle did not find an answer in the documentation. I installed the application muPdf from AppStore and it crashes with the same pdf file.

Comment: @Saamer the app exits and calls the method AppDelegate.ReceiveMemoryWarning, iOS stops the application due to lack of memory

Comment: I meant could you share the code where you are launching the PDF, so we can improve on it